# How can I get a substring of the strings returned from a foreach loop in Node.js when connected to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs, truncate, substr

Problem: .substring() does not process when I connect my code to MongoDB Atlas.

Background:
I'm new to coding and I am creating a blog where I need to render the posts to a blog route and to a dynamic route using route parameters and the posts need to be saved to a MongoDB Atlas server. 
I need to show only the first 100 characters in each post and then lead the user to another page using a "Read More" link.
When I use localhost:3000 to render the data, the blog posts are successfully truncated using .substring(0, 100), but when I connect to MongoDB Atlas the error message "Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined." If I remove .substring() everything processes properly so is there another way of truncating the strings?

I couldn't find much online but so far I have tried MongoDB's $substrBytes and $substr(deprecated).

```
<% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>
    <!-- Render the postTitle value as the title of the journal entry -->
    <h2><%= post.title %> </h2>
    <p>
    <!-- Render the postBody value and truncate the blog post to 100 
    characters -->
    <%= post.content.substring(0, 100) + '...'%>
    <!-- Add a link to see the full blog post on a separate page -->
    <a href="/posts/<%= post._id %>">Read More</a>
    </p>
    <% }) %>
```

Expected results: ...Read More
Actual results: TypeError:...\blog.ejs. Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue with mongo Atlas server, these normal things should work same as like on your localhost, I suspect there is data in your localhost vs missing in mongo atlas database(may be a data issue) !! when it said ""Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined"" it does mean "post.content" is undefined, can you print post object and check what's happening when connected to mongo atlas vs localhost..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly some of your posts do not have content, Write the following safe code

```
<%= (post.content)? post.content.substring(0, 100) + '...' : 'No content available' %>
```